# Redis and sidekiq ECONNREFUSED

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I deploy my rails app and a redis server (on port 13160 on the same server.
After i try to launch my app it returns me:

```
Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:13160 (ECONNREFUSED)):
```

The function where it stops in my code is

```
UpdatesWorker.perform_async
```

The thing is when I write RAILS_ENV=production rails runner UpdatesWorker.perform_async into my rails app then it works.

Comment: Are you sure that redis is running? Try to connect to redis with the rails console. `redis = Redis.new(:host => host, :port => port, :password => password)`

Comment: It returns me:  => #<Redis client v3.0.4 for redis://127.0.0.1:13160/0> 
Btw I deploy redis server with wget and not apt-get so to run my redis server i have to make Path/to/redis/src/redis-server path/to/redis/redis.config Don't know if it changes something. Plus there something i don't understand who is suppose to launch redis server (my rails app or automaticaly launch)?

Comment: Yes i found my problem. It was coming from my host (i'm on shared host) which didn't give me the IP adress. So it wasn't 127.0.0.1.